# Python two condition if else

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have code in dictionary form that I want to convert to pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1.5,2.8,9.3],b=[3.2,3.3,3.9],c=[13.1,4.9,15.9],d=[1.1,1.9,2.9]))
```

This data is made up but in the real scenario I am using a function similar to this. **But how do I modify the if else for if x is greater than 4 or less than 2?** At the moment I am only defining if x is greater than 4...

```
def _print(x):
    if (x < 4).any():
        print('Zone %s does not make setpoint, see box plot below for the distribution of the data in DegF' % x.name)

    else:
        print('Zone %s meets zone temperature setpoint' % x.name)
        print('The average is %s in DegF' % x.mean())
    print('---')

df.apply(lambda x: _print(x))
```

Comment: `if x > 4 or x < 2`…!? Or reversed to `if 2 <= x <= 4: ... else: ...`…!? Or `if x in range(2, 5): ... else: ...`…!?

Comment: what are you *actually* trying to achieve? `df.apply` isn't designed for printing strings. It's hugely inefficient to use it for this purpose.

Comment: You're either looking for how to use the [Logical or operator](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/python-logical-operators/) or how to write [Elif statements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm), but the way you phrased your question it's hard to tell which you want.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after in terms of axes and the exact logic but it seems that you would preferably want to end up with a dataframe something like: `df[df.apply(pd.Series.between, args=(2, 4)).any(axis=1)].mean()` and then use the data from that to produce something...

Comment: Do you know how I can modify this? On my real data set I am also creating a series box plot for data that does not meet setpoint..

Comment: Jon Clements can you show me in an answer for example of the `df[df.apply(pd.Series.between, args=(2, 4)).any(axis=1)].mean()`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in applying a conditional filter to your dataframe then you could do the following:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x>4) | df.apply(lambda x: x<2)]
```

Then as a second step you can take the average of the columns which fulfilled your conditions:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x>4) | df.apply(lambda x: x<2)].mean()
```

This will let you know which columns have met your conditions with what mean.

Comment: Is it possible to call out separate functions as you describe above? For example If the  data is in between 2 and 4, just print the average. But if the data is outside of this range create a box plot.... Thank you

Comment: You could take the first step as I mentioned above. That gives you a dataframe with numbers (where the condition is met) and NaNs where it is not met. Then you can apply a function that investigates the columns of this dataframe: if all rows are NaNs then create a boxplot, if there is at least one none NaN then print the mean.

Comment: One thing that is really important is that I keep the name of the column.. On my real data issue its how I will go back and find out where the problems based on the name of the column, is there anyway that you could give me one more tip on how to retain the column name? Basically the example that I have is if the data is outside the range of 2-4, create a box plot. Else print the .mean(). Any methods of attacking this problem is greatly appreciated, especially if I dont have to use an external pandas series.

Answer (score -1):

```
if x > 4 or x < 2:
    //blah
```

That is how you define that in python (and mostly any other language just replace or with `||`.) If you are asking how to make that into an if statement. I don't understand what else you might be asking.

Comment: I get this error because of Pandas series, `'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index a') ` Any ideas on how to modify is greatly appreciated...